# Cant write to newly created files

Tags: php, linux, apache

Now, this is an odd issue that suddenly started happening on my server (Arch Linux, fully updated). I have a php script that takes a file, copies it and then reads the copy. I can post the code if necessary but its worked fine for years.

I noticed things were not working right, and checking the server revealed that PHP can seemingly no longer write to files anymore. It can create them, because they do show up in the directory, but they are all size 0. Also, the PHP script can seemingly no longer write to the error file either, which it was fully capable of doing before.

Ive checked permissions of the directory and its owned by the user **http** which is the user apache runs under on Arch Linux. I havent made any recent modifications to the script, but I did recently update PHP to 5.5.13.

Any ideas what might have gone wrong here?

Here's the directory permissions listing

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 http http      0 Jun 10 07:44 78ab9c85d0f0a9415d154c938ede2a62
-rwxr-xr-x 1 http http   2198 Feb 15 04:53 script_new.php
-rwxr-xr-x 1 http http   2174 Feb 15 04:53 script.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 http http      0 Jun 10 07:44 php-error.log
```

Comment: I just love when people say "its worked fine for years". Have you ever heard concept of getting old? :) So you better post your code for us to be able to help you (at least part which creates/writes files). As to your problem: do you have SElinux enabled?

Comment: Check the free disk space on that partition.

Comment: Fully aware that the code can get obsolete, however, since it cant even write to the error log file all of sudden, I figured the issues must be somewhere else. The code is only like 2 years old though, so not that ancient. No SELinux enabled.

Comment: Randy Orrison, I believe you have the answer.. *facepalm*. That partition is actually 100% full, so that might be the issue right there! Cant believe I didnt check that before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your parition is most probably full. do `df -h` and check if any partitions' Use% have hit 100%

Answer (score 1):

It just a thought. But try to give read-write permission to all level of that particular file.. I mean to say give 777 permission to that particular file and check again. I know, for a matter of fact giving 777 is vulnerable. But try it for only file which you are editing..

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried setting 777 for the entire directory, to no avail.

Comment: Not the entire directory.. just set the 777 permission for that file which you are going to edit from PHP script..